# Multiplicate a number per an elevated parenthesis

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have a little problem in calculating the second derivative of a function, because I don't know how to compute this operation:

$(2x)*(x+2)^2$

I have to calculate the $(x+2)^2$ in this way: $(x^2+4+4x)$ and then multiply every term per $(2x)$ or there is another and faster way?

Thanks

Comment: Product rule and power rule

Comment: It's important to know the product and power rules - but in this very simple problem  multiplying everything out and then differentiating twice is probably faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of doing it, either by using a combination of the product and inner function rules as in the other answer, or simplifying the expression just as you specify:

$$(2x) \cdot (x+2)^2 = (2x) \cdot (x^2 + 4x + 4) = 2x^3 + 8x^2 + 8x$$

The second derivative of which is $12x + 16$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the product rule $(fg)' = f'g + g'f$ with $f = 2x$ and $g = (x+2)^2$ so you get $$(2x(x+2)^2)' = (2x)'(x+2)^2 + ((x+2)^2)'(2x)$$

giving $$2(x+2)^2 + 4x(x+2) = 2(x+2)(x+2+2x) = 2(x+2)(3x+2)$$ and then differentiating again with the product rule with $f = x+2$ and  $g = 3x+2$ gives the derivative of $(x+2)(3x+2)$ as $$(x+2)'(3x+2) + (3x+2)'(x+2) = 3x+2+3(x+2)$$

and accounting for the factor of $2$ gives you what you want: $4(3x+4)$

Comment: Is that faster than going $(2x)(x+2)^2=2x^3+8x^2+8x$ so the second derivative is $12x+16$?

Comment: Probably not, in hindsight. Oh well, should still hopefully be informative to the OP for cases when the product rule *is* faster.